# mysql: setting unique index for autoincrement field

Tags: mysql, indexing

when creating a new table i'm defining a field called ID with index primary and autoincrement.
when adding new records it's not possible defining the same ID twice so i was wondering: what's the deal about setting index "unique" for ID? is it required, will it improve performance? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to set it unique, by setting it as auto increment and primary key you have already forced uniqueness over there. You dont need seperate unique constraint here.

Answer (score -1):

You can not add the multiple records with the same ID.

if you want to create the multiple record , firstly delete the primary or auto incr...

Then it will be inserted.

Comment: i don't want to add records with the same id, i was just wondering why i should also add an unique index when there's already an autoincrement index ..